# usb debug authorixation not shown (how to push files onto unauthorized adb device(rooted device) (4.4.2))

Tags: android, adb

i have a lava iris atom 2 which was in kitkat 4.4.2
i installed xposed -- (gravitybox, eggster, monsterui)
i was satisfied with my new lolipopish look
but only thing annoying was the settings it had the light theme
and all the icons were white so they were invisible
then i used apk-editor to change icons
actually i used only wifi icon to be changed then i compiled it with the same apk-editor
then replaced it with root browser, 
guess what the settings was in accesible
i thought restarting might fix the problem
then i had the two errors constantly poping up

Unfortunately, the process
com.android.systemui has 
stopped

AND

Unfortunately, the process
com.android.phone has 
stopped

i cant even use my phone for a sec
i have a pattern lock which takes 3 sec to complete
total time i can access the phone 5 to 10 sec
i quickkly completed the pattern and the launcher responded
then i couldnt find settings
in status bar it was the same no settings
i am hardly able to open status bar and launcher

i tried flashing stock rom
no progress its blank(device not detected i guess)
all drivers are present, i tried adb (waiting for device in fastboot mode) (i guess because it is unauthoritised)
i have backed up settings.apk in case of a bad thing but i cant push it either.
i didnt get a prompt to allow adb

my recovery is dead too
i tried cwm ported for my device and its dead
i didnt have the backup

what should i do??
can i push it / bypass prompt
i get only some sec to wait for allowing it
i tried sending requests non stop through cmd 
i get some sound (notification ) but no prompt

help me guys.
i really need it

Answer (score 0):

If your device didn't connect to your system then, you need to follow the step and install the driver.

Step 1: Download and extract the zip file on your computer then connect your android smartphone via Lava USB cable to your personal computer or laptop.

Step 2: Click on the Start button or you can also press WIN key to directly active start menu then either you have to right click on the “Computer” option or you can also press Shift+F10 key to open the cascading menu and choose “Manage” option. Click on the “Device Manager” option in the Computer Management dialog box. Now you can see your mobile name or number with yellow triangle icon in the right side pan. That means android device is properly not installed on your computer or laptop.

Step 3: Press right mouse button which has yellow triangle option then you have to click on Update Driver Software option > Click on the “Browse my computer for driver software” option > Select the folder by clicking on the Browse… button now, you will get complete path of USB driver software file then click on the Next button > Now, your USB driver updating process will be start. After successfully finish the USB driver updating process, finally click on the close button.

I hope you will get required USB driver of Lava Smartphone and also helps you to easily install Lava USB driver on your PC or laptop.

If nothing helps then, please try to use another data cable...